# Novice Javascript query

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple question, I have tried searching forums but I've not been able to find what I think I need. Below is a bit of script which works as I expect:

```
$(function(){

var ProjType = $("#cfs_i3_cf3");


$(ProjType).change(function() {
$("#cfs_h3").css("background-color", "red");

alert('okay then!');
});

});
```

Basically, the ID `#cfs_i3_cf3` represents a drop-down box and when it changes, the colour changes.

I want to advance this a little and say:

If `#cfs_i3_cf3 = A` then `color = X` otherwise `color = Y`

Very simple, but struggling with the syntax and hopefully it's a very simple answer as I'm not used to javascript.

Many thanks in advance!
James

Comment: You should do that using CSS classes / selectors instead.

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle for it?

Comment: *If "`#cfs_i3_cf3" = "A" `* What does `"A"` mean?

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach to do this is:
You listen for changes in the select box and then on its change get the select box's value and if it is one then color the paragraph red else yellow.

```js
$(function(){
  var ProjType = $("#cfs_i3_cf3");
  $(ProjType).change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "1")
    {
      $("#cfs_h3").css("background-color", "red");
    }
    else
    {
      $("#cfs_h3").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cfs_i3_cf3">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<p id="cfs_h3">THIS IS THE OUTPUT</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add additional refactor. Sorry! I simply think jQuery is doing to same thing but why load extra library?

```js
function switchColor(select){
  var redOrNot = select.value == 'red' ? true: false;
  var el = document.getElementById('cfs_h3');

  if (redOrNot) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = select.value;
  } else {
    el.style.backgroundColor = select.value;
  }
}

/* if you don't need logic, you can simply do 
el.style.backgroundColor = select.value; since the color logic 
is already embedded in the HTML.
*/
```

```html
<select id="cfs_i3_cf3" onchange="switchColor(this)">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
<option value="red">One</option>
<option value="yellow">Two</option>
</select>
<p id="cfs_h3">THIS IS THE OUTPUT</p>
```